# How to access cookie value in HTML(not in controller) using angularJs

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I want to access cookie value in html, I need to check one condition saying ng-if='cookievalue==1' ....so that i can hide and show the content

Answer (score 5):

To get hold of the cookie in HTML, you first need to store its reference /value in angularJS controller scope. Only when you associate with $scope you can access it in html

Answer (score 3):

Manasi is right, you have to have a controller in order to access values from HTML.

Your HTML:

```
<div ng-if="cookievalue==1"> ... </div>
```

Your controller:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$cookies', function($scope, $cookies) {

  $scope.cookievalue = $cookies.get('mycookie');

}]);
```